# Вызов .ToString()

Tags: c#

```
string s = null;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(s));//1
Console.WriteLine(s);//2
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());//3
```

1. Почему в первом случае не выдает NULL reference?
2. Почему во-втором случае не выдает NULL reference? Если я, не ошибаюсь, то в методе Console.WriteLine() ко всем переменным вызывается метод .ToString() не явно.
3. Почему когда явно указываю .ToString() выдает NULL reference?
   Можно ссылки по данным вопросам или ключевые слова для поиска нужной информации.

Вот il-код программы:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldnull
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  ldloc.0
IL_0004:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Convert::ToString(string)
IL_0009:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000e:  nop
IL_000f:  ldloc.0
IL_0010:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0015:  nop
IL_0016:  ldloc.0
IL_0017:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
IL_001c:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0021:  nop
IL_0022:  ret
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По поводу вывода `null` через `Console.WriteLine()`, [MSDN говорит](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written to the standard output stream.

То есть `Console.WriteLine(null)` выводит один лишь перевод строки. Это объясняет пример (2). В этом случае `Console.WriteLine` согласно документации не имеет права тупо вызывать `ToString` (тем более что мы вызвали перегрузку со строкой, там конвертация точно не нужна). Для того, чтобы соответствовать документации, функция обязана проверять свой аргумент на `null`. Это можно увидеть прямо в [исходниках текущей версии .NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,454):

```
if (value==null) {
    WriteLine();
}
else { ...
```

---

Далее, согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8(v=vs.110).aspx) на `Convert.ToString(string s)`, значение не меняется:

> value is returned unchanged.

Поэтому `Convert.ToString(s)` возвращает `null`, а уж вывод `null` работает без проблем, как и в примере (2). Это объясняет пример (1).

---

Ну и наконец пример (3), вызов `s.ToString()` есть вызов метода по `null`-ссылке, который закономерно ведёт к `NullReferenceException`.